# UI5 Control (menu, activitysheet, ..) openBy not showing for OverflowToolbar (dependent on UI5 version)

Tags: menu, controls, sapui5

Observing different behaviour when opening an dependet element (e.g sap.m.menu) by function openBy(control=OverflowToolbar) when called from Button in Overflow Area of OverflowToolbar

In my App with Version 1.52 the menu is not visible again, when runnig at 1.71 the Menu is shown as expected:
[menu shown in 1.71](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbKSN.png)

I build a test App to reproduce this behavior but my test App can not really reproduce this issue, the menu there is just flickering / not visible (1.52,1.60 and 1.71), do you have any advise?

For Coding see: [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ui5-openby-try-osjxk)

The solution from here: [ActionSheet openBy Toolbar](https://answers.sap.com/questions/12576528/actionsheet-in-overflowtoolbar-doesn%27t-stay-open.html) is also possible for me, but I'am intrested why sometimes the Control is schown when openBy and sometimes not.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing that in a setTimeOut:

```
    setTimeout(function () {
                actionSheet.openBy(oButton);
            });
```

Comment: Thanks for your advise, works for Elements where OverflowlayoutData closeOverflowOnInteraction<>"false"